# prepareForSegue triggering didSet before viewDidLoad has loaded all IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift

I have a very simple setup in which  I show a list of users inside a `TableViewController`. Whenever the user clicks on one of the rows, he is directed to that user's profile.

```
case "ShowProfileSegue":
  let profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileViewController
  let cell = sender as! SearchResultTableViewCell
  profileVC.user = cell.user
  break
```

In my `ProfileViewController` I have the following `didSet` callback:

```
var user : User {
    didSet {
        if let newUser = self.user {
            profileNameLabel.text = newUser.name
            profileDescriptionLabel.text = ", ".join(newUser.roles)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that whenever the `didSet` callback is running, both my labels are `nil` causing the program to crash. I thought using `didSet` to update the UI was pretty nifty but apparently it doesn't seem to work all the times. What other ways could I handle this use case?

[image: Crash]

Comment: Simply have your `didSet` bail out if the labels are nil.

Comment: Simple enough! I just did not have any of the UI init logic inside the `viewDidLoad` as I was trying to explore some of the newer Swift features! Although it does seem a bit dirty to have that `if` in the `didSet`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply have your `didSet` bail out if the labels are nil:

```
var user : User {
    didSet {
        if profileNameLabel != nil { // bail out if still nil
            if let newUser = self.user {
                profileNameLabel.text = newUser.name
                profileDescriptionLabel.text = ", ".join(newUser.roles)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After `viewDidLoad` is called, the outlets are loaded and the labels will not be nil, and now your `didSet` will be useful. Until then, there is no interface to configure!

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```
 var appDetail: AppDetail? {
        didSet {
            if let d = appDetail, let _ = view {
                nameLabel.text = d.info.name
                iconImageView.setImageWithURL(d.detail.iconURL)
                descriptionLabel.text = d.detail.introduction
            }
        }
    }
```

In fact, `let _ = view` wil load view and all IBOutlet will not be nil any more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use didSet in profileNameLabel and profileDescriptionLabel, such as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileNameLabel: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        profileNameLabel.text = user.name
    }
}
```

Because now you're setting user before the actual segue (*prepare*ForSegue) and that's why you can't have your outlets set at that point. Adding property observers to outlets is a good way to know when they're set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `loadViewIfNeeded()` like this:

```
var user : User {
    didSet {
        loadViewIfNeeded()
        if let newUser = self.user {
            profileNameLabel.text = newUser.name
            profileDescriptionLabel.text = ", ".join(newUser.roles)
        }
    }
}
```